# Show a WebApp hosted in localhost on windowsform

Tags: vb.net, web-applications, localhost

I have a custom HMI (Human machine interface) programmed in VB.NET. I want to show a webapp that is hosted in other pc (localhost:888) on my HMI. To do this, I put a webbrowser in my windowsform. I have never done this, so for testing I tried with [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) in the webbrowser URL and it works.
Now I want to show the webapp in this webbrowser. What URL should I set ?

My PC and the Windows Server PC are in a local area network, the IP's are:

My PC: 192.168.1.99

Server: 192.168.1.90

Answer (score 0):

I done it, sorry if this was a very noob question.
I did 192.168.1.90:888